# Implement a search bar

Tags: java, android

I want to implement a search bar, which the user can write something and it will search for in the page.

I read about it in the android developer and found it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

However, I read that it's available only for api 11 and higher.

Is there any implementation or another search widget for api lower than 11?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't answer your specific question, but you can parse the text of the page itself using the Regex library (see the [Tutorial Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)). Admittedly you would have to put some sort of efficiency measures in there somehow, this isn't Lua after all, but it can be done manually.

Comment: No problem, but I think you will be stuck with this method if you want to support devices < Honeycomb is all.